# Can I charge a lead acid battery with a lithium ion battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am asking specifically about automotive 12V lead acid batteries but I suppose the principles may be universal.

If I were to connect a fully charged 15V Li-ion battery to a discharged 12V lead acid battery (at around 11.5V), would the Li-ion battery charge the lead acid battery?

My theory is that since the potential at the battery terminals is about 14.7V when the car's alternator is running, attaching a 15V battery will have the same effect. Is this correct or will it result in some horrible acid flinging hydrogen explosion?

Comment: The car battery would be fine, and would be charged - but the current draw on the Li-ion might be harmful to it.

Comment: So by adding a current limiting circuit between the two, would that protect the Li battery while still charging the Pb?

Comment: Yes! As long as you have a circuit that limits current to a level safe for the Li-ion battery.

Comment: @tahmid Do you know of any example products for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could charge a 12V battery with a 15V battery. Since you can not control any parameters when charging this way (arguably you control voltage) it is not optimal, but a constant voltage charger is probably good enough for a lead acid battery but possibly harm your lithium ion battery. With other technologies you probably would like to control the current and possibly the charge cycle.

There are many modes of charging. I include this link after a quick google search where you can read the section "Basic Charging Methods" on this page http://www.mpoweruk.com/chargers.htm.

Comment: Would it be possible to add some kind of charger between the two batteries to improve the charge cycle? Possibly in a way that would not drain the lithium battery once the lead battery is full?

Answer (score -1):

I have jump started cars using an 18 volt ryobi lithium battery,  alligator clips, wires taped to lithium battery terminals ,30 seconds and ,voila, it starts .Easy to carry with you when travelling. Sometimes people charging and using iphones ,while parked can get a surprise when they try to start their engine ,and realise ,the juice has gone to the phone. ENTER 18 V LIT BATT. to the rescue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).